# No sound output after upgrading or installing Loki

Tags: release-loki, sound

First off I had installed Freya days before Loki was official. Loved it everything ran great. I decided to try Loki and had absolutely no output devices for sound. After a while, I decided I liked Freya (since sound worked immediately) and now I have reinstalled Freya and updated it. But still no output devices for audio. It is an HP Pavilion g120cy with B&O audio. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you dual booting with Windows? If so, the following steps may help:

1. Shut down your computer.
2. Boot into elementary OS.
3. Restart, and boot into elementary OS again.

After booting into Windows on my XPS 13, I have to follow these steps to get sound working on eOS. For details on why this problem occurs, see [the XPS 13 page in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(2015)#Audio).

Comment: Nope, no dual booting. After installing Freya the first time I went straight for it. I am used to Ubuntu and mint so I am familiar with Linux in general this one has me stumped because my original install worked fine.

Comment: So i am able to see (but not in select audio output) that it sees I have a built in audio digital stereo (hdmi) as an audio device in VLC player I can choose but hat doesn't seem to help any...

Comment: Admins please just delete this thread the lack of help is forcing me to move back to other flavors... I wish it would have worked out.